# solve the error "Cannot find the object "" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.'

Tags: sql, asp.net-web-api

I am having a stored proc called "usp_bulk_import_request_pending" with 2 parameters. I executed in the data base and it is working as I want. 
But
Now i am calling this stored procedure from webapi and passing 2 parameters.
I am getting the error as "Cannot find the object "table name" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.'

Web api code:

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("SaveImport")]
public void SaveImport([FromBody] dynamic param)
{         
 var args = new List<DBParameter>();
args.Add(new DBParameter("@requestorId", DbType.AnsiString, param.Sysm.ToString()));
            args.Add(new DBParameter("@importFileType", DbType.AnsiString, param.ImportFileType.ToString()));
            SQL.ExecuteNonQuery(Connection, "usp_bulk_import_request_pending", args.ToArray());  //error here
        }
```

Ajax call:

```
Save: function (me) {
        Ext.Msg.confirm('Save', 'Are you sure you want to save imported data?', function (button) {
            if (button === 'yes') {
                var sysm = BIACore.Security.User.userId,
                    importfileType = 'COST';
                var params = { ImportFileType: importfileType, Sysm: sysm };
                Ext.getBody().mask('Save is in progress, please wait.')
                Ext.Ajax.request({
                    url: 'api/CostImport/SaveImport',
                    method: 'POST',
                    cache: false,
                    scope: this,
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json"
                    },
                    params: JSON.stringify(params),
                    success: function (response) {
                        Ext.getBody().unmask();
                        var tabPanel = this.getCurrent(),
                            currentTab = tabPanel.getActiveTab();
                        if (currentTab.title != 'Cost Import') {
                            tabPanel.setActiveTab(tabPanel.down('#costImport'));
                        } else {
                            var grid = this.getCurrent().getActiveTab();
                            var sysm = BIACore.Security.User.userId,
                                params = {
                                    RowId: '',
                                    ORIG_AIRPORT_CODE: '',
                                    DEST_AIRPORT_CODE: '',
                                    SERVICE_LEVEL: '',
                                    CURRENCY_CODE: '',
                                    LONG_TERM_COST: '',
                                    SHORT_TERM_COST: '',
                                    LONG_TERM_PERSISTENT_COST_DATE: '',
                                    SHORT_TERM_PERSISTENT_COST_DATE: '',
                                    CREATE_USER_NAME: sysm,
                                    ERRORS: '',
                                };
                            var store = grid.getStore();
                            store.getProxy().extraParams = params;
                            store.load();
                        }
                        Ext.MessageBox.alert('Save', 'Successfully saved import data.');                   
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        Ext.getBody().unmask();
                        var responseReturn = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                        Ext.MessageBox.show({
                            title: 'Save',
                            msg: responseReturn.ExceptionMessage,
                            icon: Ext.MessageBox.ERROR,
                            buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        }, this);
    }
```

I am unable to find where i am going wrong?

Comment: I'd guess that you're using a different account with different permissions between logging into the DB directly and the API. It's also possible that the permissions are IP/location based, so 127.0.0.X has permissions, but 192.168.0.X doesn't, for example.

Comment: Has the user of the web api been granted rights on all the tables involved in the procedure?

Comment: yes .The user is having all the rights for the tables involved in stored proc. When I am trying to execute the stored proc in the data base, it is executing fine..but when i tried from web api then only the error is coming.

Comment: are you using the same user from SQL Server Management studio and from the C# code?

Answer (score 0):

try for it

```
 SQL.ExecuteNonQuery(Connection, "[dbo].usp_bulk_import_request_pending", args.ToArray());
```

insted of

```
 SQL.ExecuteNonQuery(Connection, "usp_bulk_import_request_pending", args.ToArray());
```

and set execute permission to your user for this sp